# How to create and remove row dynamically using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

This is my code

```
<table id="cont">    
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="no" id="no"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is my jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var no="";
     $('#no').keyup(function(){
     no = $("#no").val();
     for(var i=1; i<no; i++)
     {
        ++j;

        $('<tr class="field"><td></td><td><input name="qty[]" type="text" id="qty[0]" /></td></tr>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#cont');
     }
     });

    if(i==1)
    {
        $('.field').remove();
    }

});
```

I would like to create and remove row dynamically depending on an input field(no id) and it works fine upto 19 but if i input 20 then it create 20 with extra 1 row as well as i remove zero from 20 then it should be kept 2 rows but it display all rows(21).

How can i solve it , Please any help?

Comment: can't duplicate ID in a page..by defintion they must be unique, and using `[]` in an `id` is just a bad idea. Stick to alpha-numeric characters. Main problem is you keep adding and only remove if value=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is you only ever add rows. Here's a solution that provides a bit of timeout after keyup, then replaces all the rows. It's not entirely clear what your overall objective is with this UI.

Note that top row is wrapped in `<thead>` and `<tbody>` is used for data rows:

```
var row = '<tr class="field"><td>Row text</td><td><input name="qty[]" type="text" /></td></tr>';
var num_rows=0;
$('#no').keyup(function () {
   num_rows= $(this).val();;
    if (!isNaN(num_rows)) {/* make sure is a number, can add extra condition to limit number*/
        setTimeout(createRows, 300);/* slight delay to give user time to type*/
    } else {
        alert('numbers only please')
    }
});

function createRows(){
    var rowHtml='';
    for ( i=0;i<num_rows;i++){
        rowHtml+=row;
    }
    $('#cont tbody').html( rowHtml)

}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/H4MHs/

**EDIT:** I suspect that this approach is completely off track from what you really want, but follows your methodology. Since objective was never spelled out that's all we can go on

Comment: Thanks a lot charlietfl. but How to post dynamic input field value and How to receive in php dynamically.

Comment: post it based on what event? Look into **[jQuery AJAX API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)**, also many tutorials on web for `jQuery php AJAX`

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to convert the value from your field into an integer using `parseInt` before you use it in the loop.

I'm pretty sure jQuery's `.val()` will always return a string.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that this is what you need:

Html:

```
Number of field:<div id='nbElem'></div>
<table id="cont">    
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="no" id="no"/></td>
  <td id='field'></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Js:

```
$('#no').keyup(function(){
    var $val = parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    var $nbQtity = $('.qtity').length;

    if($val <= $nbQtity){
        for(var i = $val; i < $nbQtity; i++){
            $('#q_'+i).remove();
        }
    }else{
        for(var i = $nbQtity; i < $val; i++){
         $('<input name="qty[]" class="qtity"'
           +' type="text" id="q_'+i+'" />')
             .fadeIn('slow')
             .appendTo('#field');
        }
    }
    $('#nbElem').text($val);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYtbs/

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest and the easiest way of adding rows

```
<table id="options-table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Input-Box-One</td>
        <td>Input-Box-Two</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td>
        <td><input class="del" type="button" value="Delete" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td>
        <td><input class="add" type="button" value="Add More" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

If we want more rows then we have to add new row to the table.
Put this code in script

```
$('.add').live('click',function(){
$(this).val('Delete');
$(this).attr('class','del');

var appendTxt = "<tr><td><input type="text" name="input_box_one[]" /></td><td><input type="text" name="input_box_two[]" /></td><td><input class="add" type="button" value="Add More" /></td></tr>";
$("tr:last").after(appendTxt); });
```

Delete a row from Table.

```
$('.del').live('click',function(){
$(this).parent().parent().remove(); });
```